# Linear gradient not working in Safari and Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, safari, linear-gradients

I can get the below linear-gradient to show up on Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari or Internet Explorer.

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(5,5,5,0) 48%, rgba(5,5,5,1) 49%, rgba(5,5,5,1) 51%, rgba(5,5,5,0) 52%, rgba(5,5,5,0) 54%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(48%,rgba(5,5,5,0)), color-stop(49%,rgba(5,5,5,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(5,5,5,1)), color-stop(52%,rgba(5,5,5,0)), color-stop(54%,rgba(5,5,5,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(5,5,5,0) 48%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 49%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 51%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 52%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 54%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(5,5,5,0) 48%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 49%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 51%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 52%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 54%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(5,5,5,0) 48%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 49%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 51%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 52%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 54%);
background:linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(5,5,5,0) 48%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 49%,rgba(5,5,5,1) 51%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 52%,rgba(5,5,5,0) 54%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00050505', endColorstr='#00050505',GradientType=1 );
```

(I'm testing Safari on Ubuntu using both Wine and modern.ie virtualbox, IE on the latter)

Comment: Safari 5 on Wine (PlayOnLinux), Safari 5.17 on Windows, IE 10

Answer (score 1):

This is an amazing tool that I use for all of my gradients. I've never had a problem with it! Sorry I can't figure out your exact problem but maybe this will help.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Try using -webkit-gradient: /* Your gradient code */;